# markdown2 module - how do I convert a a markdown file from within a Python script?

Tags: python, markdown

I am using markdown2 module (found here: https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) The module is great but documentation is lacking.

I attempted something simple like converting a file using a Python script. I wanted to then use this to convert a batch of files. But even the first part is hitting a dead end. My code:

```
from markdown2 import Markdown
markdowner = Markdown()
markdowner.convert("file.md", "file.htm")
```

Could someone show me how?

Comment: There are examples [in the repository](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/blob/master/sandbox/wiki.py).

Answer (score 1):

NVM, I got the answer (and not from the repository mentioned above). Here's a simple Pythonic two-liner:

```
from markdown2 import Markdown
with open("file.htm", 'w') as output_file: output_file.write(Markdown().convert(open("file.md").read()))
```